# "Arithmetically diverse" infinite binary string

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

For $a,b \in \omega$ with $a > 0$, let $f_{a,b}: \omega\to\omega$ be defined by $n \mapsto an+b$. What is an example of an infinite binary string $s:\omega\to\{0,1\}$ with the following property?

> Whenever $(a,b), (a_1,b_1)\in (\omega\setminus\{0\})\times \omega$ with $(a,b)\neq (a_1,b_1)$, then $s\circ f_{a,b} \neq s\circ f_{a_1,b_1}$.

Comment: That's right @bof - sorry for the bad variable choice, have changed the string variable to $s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s$ consist of $2^{2^k}$ zeros, followed by the same number of ones, for increasing $k$:
$$0^21^2\, 0^{16}1^{16}\, 0^{256}1^{256}\,0^{65536}1^{65536}\dots$$
Observe that all but finitely many blocks of 1s of $s\circ f_{a,b}$ have size of the form $\lfloor2^{2^{k}}/a\rfloor$ or $\lceil 2^{2^k}/a\rceil$.

We claim that we cannot keep having $k>j$ and $2^{2^k}/{a_1}\le 2^{2^j}/{a_2}+1$ (and therefore all $s\circ f_{a,b}$ are distinct).

Indeed, when this happens then $2^{2^k-2^j}\le a_1/{a_2}+a_1 2^{-2^j}$ is bounded. But as $k>j\to\infty$, $2^{2^k-2^j}$ is unbounded.

(Note that $2^k/a_1=2^{k-1}/a_2$ with $a_1=4$ and $a_2=2$, so a single-exponential $2^k$ in place of a double-exponential $2^{2^k}$ is not enough for this construction.)

Comment: Very neat construction - thank you very much!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen thanks for another interesting question.

Answer (score 4):

2 approaches:

1. Generate $b$ randomly, having $b(n)$ be $0$ with probability $1/2$ and having each $b(n)$ be independent. Then for each $(a,b)$ and $(a_1,b_1)$, the probability that
   $$
   b\circ f_{a,b}=b\circ f_{a_1,b_1}
   $$
   is $0$. Summing over all countably many such pairs, we still get a probability of $0$, so with probability $1$, our string works.
2. Generate $b$ greedily. Go through pairs $(a,b),(a_1,b_1)$ in some order and for each, choose two entries in our string very far out to force disagreement.

Comment: So what does $s$ look like concretely? Given $n\in \omega$ what is $s(n)$?